# Laravel 5.2 :How to display time like this?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2, I want to show the article's creation time like this:

```
created_at                               displaying
in  1  day                                today
2-10 days                                 (2-10) days ago
>10  days                                  show creation date directly
```

How to do it?
Thanks in advance!

**edit:**

controller:

```
  public function show($id)
    {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        return view('show', compact('article'));
    }
```

view:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{$article->title}}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">{{$article->content}}</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{$article->created_at}}</small></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where should I use  `Carbon` 's  `diffForHumans()`?

Comment: try using Carbon: http://carbon.nesbot.com/.

Comment: In the view: {{$article->created_at->diffForHumans()}}

Answer (score 2):

You can define [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for custom attribute

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class User extends Model
{

    public function getPrettyCreatedAtAttribute()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $age = $this->created_at->diffInDays($now);
        if ($age < 2) {
            return 'today';
        }
        elseif ($age < 10) {
            return '(2-10) days ago';
        }
        else {
            return $this->created_at;
        }
    }

}
```

Then in view

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{$article->title}}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">{{$article->content}}</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{$article->pretty_created_at}}</small></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you check put the Carbon diff for humans feature?

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Since the `created_at` field is a Carbon instance by default you can call carbon methods on it like so:

```
$post->created_at->diffForHumans()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `\Carbon\Carbon` class and diff for human like here:

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Answer (score 1):

$diff = $post->created_at->diffInDays()

```
$diff = $post->created_at->diffInDays()
```

Now the logic:

```
if($diff == 1)
  echo 'today';
elseif($diff >1 && $diff <= 10)
  echo "$diff days ago";
else
  echo $diff->created_at;
```

**Note** this is only for your particular situation. Otherwise you should use Carbon' s `diffForHumans()`

Answer (score 0):

here is tutorial for crabon: [More](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon)

```
 $dt     = Carbon::now();
 $past   = $dt->subMonth();
 $future = $dt->addMonth();

 echo $dt->subDays(10)->diffForHumans();     // 10 days ago
 echo $dt->diffForHumans($past);             // 1 month ago
  echo $dt->diffForHumans($future);           // 1 month before
```